# Java 9 HttpClient hangs

Tags: java, http2, java-9

I'm experimenting with `HTTP/2` client from `jdk 9-ea+171`. The code is taken from [this example](https://labs.consol.de/development/2017/03/14/getting-started-with-java9-httpclient.html):

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(new URI("https://www.google.com/"))
    .build();

HttpResponse<String> response
        = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandler.asString());
```

But the client hangs on the last line forever. Please advice how to fix it?

Debugging shows it infinitely waits in method `waitUntilPrefaceSent()`.

Comment: I can get it to work if I use the other overload of `newBuilder` that takes a `URI` directly, and I use `http` instead of `https`. I get NPE with `https`.

Comment: It works with `http` because client uses `HTTP/1.1` as we can see from `response.version()`. I need exactly `https` and advantages of `HTTP/2` protocol.

Comment: I faced NPE when request method (e.g. GET) was not specified.

Comment: Its a bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8181430

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the latest build's implementation of a HTTP2 connection. It does not occure with previous builds.

First of all, you need to specify the `GET` method to avoid getting a null pointer exception.

What happens is that the main thread is waiting for the connection preface to be sent. It locks a count down latch to await the receival of this preface. In order to wake itself up, any `HttpClient` creates a helper thread that reads incoming traffic. This thread is supposed to wake up the main thread but sometimes, this never happens. If you run your example, often enough, you will see that this sometimes work. I guess there is a race for reading the preface.

Unfortunately, the reading of the preface does not respect any timeout either, so there is no way of waking up the main thread, other than interrupting the main thread.

Here is an official ticket: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8181430