# Java 11 HttpClient Hangs Intermittently

Tags: java, java-http-client

I am using Java 11's `HttpClient`. The client hangs intermittently and I can't figure out why -- I don't know what's causing the hang and I don't know how to reproduce it.

The code to construct the client and requests are in separate locations, so this summary shows how they are constructed:

```java
// excerpt 1: constructing the client
private HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
      .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
      .build();

// excerpt 2: constructing the request
HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .GET()
        .uri(...)
        .header(...)
        .header(...)
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .build();

// excerpt 3: sending the request
HttpResponse<String> resp = httpClient.send(req, BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Initially, all I knew was that my service was hanging -- I didn't know `HttpClient` was involved. I then threw a watchdog timer in a background thread that held a (weak) reference to the main worker thread so that if the timer expired, I could get a stack trace of what the main worker thread was doing. That gave me this stack trace (expired after five minutes):

```java
j.u.c.TimeoutException: null // I crammed the thread's stack trace into an exception to play nice with Splunk
    at j.i.m.Unsafe.park(Unknown Source)
    at j.u.c.l.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at j.u.c.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(Unknown Source)
    at j.u.c.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(Unknown Source)
    at j.u.c.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(Unknown Source)
    at j.u.c.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at j.i.n.h.HttpClientImpl.send(Unknown Source)
    at j.i.n.h.HttpClientFacade.send(Unknown Source)
    at c.a.x.d.c.MyClientClass.sendRequest(MyClientClass.java:163)
    at ...
```

I have since seen a few of these timeouts occur, in different sections of code that all use `HttpClient`, all producing the same stack trace.

I know there have been `HttpClient` bugs dating back to Java 9 that can cause hangs, but we're running on a Java 11 build from last month (IIRC) and all the bugs I've read were fixed long before that.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this, or how to reproduce it or debug it further?

Comment: Can you tell what is the output of `java --version`? Depending on the vendor some of the fixes may have been backported in different updates. Also do you know whether the request goes out with HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2? I would also suggest trying to reproduce with JDK 14 - if that's possible - or with the JDK 15 candidate.

Comment: I'm having similar problems with HttpClient. Here's another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266022/java-9-httpclient-hangs) which mentions similar problems. I'm using `AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10)`

Comment: I stopped encountering this issue after updating to `AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10)`